# How to animate a CAShapeLayer`s path to another path smoothly?

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have a `CAShapeLayer` with a specifical shape. And i want to change the path of the layer to animate its shape. But when i use `CABasicAnimation`, the animation is always not that good to match my requirement.

I try some different ways.
I have the same number of points in two paths. The points of the previous path does not go the place i want. Some straight lines occurs.
I want to animate a cloud into a circle. Here is the images show the problem.
[image] [image][image]
Help

Comment: Can you add a movie or images which demonstrate the effect?

Comment: @macmoonshine wait

Comment: @macmoonshine See the images

Answer (score 1):

You should give [CAKeyframeAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cakeyframeanimation?language=objc) with intermediate shapes a try. I think the spike in the cloud is reason for the unexpected behaviour. The intermediate shapes should transform the cloud to a convex and smooth shape (like a potato), and after that to a circle. I would try to move only the spike and its surrounding points first.